# Can mods mass-rollback a user's edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, suggested-edits

Just out of curiosity, when I flag a user for making countless bad suggested edits for a mod's attention, can/will the mod mass-rollback all edits that are deemed unacceptable?

Is there any point for me to do it myself, even before the flag is reviewed?

Comment: I don't think such functionality exist. The only benefit would be that a mod could send a mod message to the user. Rollback of bad edits can start immediately, that doesn't require a mod. If you need help you can leave a message in [The SO Tavern](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-general). Some regulars keep an eye on that room...

Comment: @rene: not the only benefit. Bringing mod attention to the roboreviewers who are approving a user's completely useless edits that need to be rolled back is much more useful than bringing attention to the edits themselves. If they all end up banned from reviewing, everyone wins.

Comment: @Wooble I agree with that. I only wanted to say that if a mod spends time on such cases be it for the ban, not for the rollbacks of edits.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, if the edits are bad enough that they merit rolling back. We do it completely manually though. Even if there are hundreds of revisions to reverse (although my record is probably only like 60 rollbacks or so).

You are well within reason to roll back the edits yourself if you so choose, but like every other edit on the site, there is no obligation to do so.

Comment: Wow, manually, that smacks of effort.

Comment: One could write a script to do that. CasperJS comes to mind. ;)

Comment: Is this a moderator privilege? Or does this require developer intervention?

Comment: Anyone can do it just like mods do it @Amal - manually.

Comment: @Amal Murali: In other words, we don't have anything beyond what is already available to other users with editing privs.

Comment: @apaul34208 Depends how frequently it needs done.  If it's a rare enough task (in most cases I'd hope that a serial bad editor would get stomped in the review queue before getting enough rep to bypass it) it might not be worth the effort to implement.  Especially since only in the most egregious cases is rolling everything back without reviewing first it justified.

Comment: I imagine in a super-rare situation where thousands or something were needed to be rolled back, a SE staff member could do it in SQL.